# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss5.x

I'm seeing a strange exception in our application, which combines both EJB3 and EJB2.  A simple purchase request (which involves writing a couple of records to a database) is failing.

Other requests which involve database calls are working fine.

The stack trace shows the code passing through several EJBs in sequence - code extracts from these classes is shown below the stack trace.

```
 2015-06-17 13:58:27,552 ERROR [org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy] com.mycompany.global.er.subsmngmnt.SubsManagementException: no account found for criteria
2015-06-17 13:58:27,627 ERROR [org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy] javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Cannot open connection
2015-06-17 13:58:27,628 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor] TransactionRolledbackException in method: public abstract com.mycompany.global.er.subsmngmnt.ejb.Account com.mycompany.global.er.subsmngmnt.ejb.AccountHome.findByPrimaryKey(java.lang.String) throws javax.ejb.FinderException,com.vizzavi.ecommerce.business.common.EcommerceException, causedBy:
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716)
        at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
        at com.mycompany.global.er.subsmngmnt.dao.oracle.AccountDaoImpl.findByCriteria(AccountDaoImpl.java:4655)
        at com.mycompany.global.er.subsmngmnt.dao.oracle.AccountDaoImpl.getUniqueERAccount(AccountDaoImpl.java:4646)
        at com.mycompany.global.er.subsmngmnt.dao.oracle.AccountDaoImpl.selectAccountUsingHibernate(AccountDaoImpl.java:4631)
        at com.mycompany.global.er.subsmngmnt.dao.oracle.AccountDaoImpl.selectAccount(AccountDaoImpl.java:894)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.java:69)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:73)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:72)
        at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_971644752.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_971644752.java)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88)
        at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_971644752.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_971644752.java)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:126)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:194)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:219)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:261)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.session.SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:101)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy305.selectAccount(Unknown Source)
        at com.mycompany.global.er.subsmngmnt.ejb.AccountBean.ejbFindByPrimaryKey(AccountBean.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.BMPPersistenceManager.callFinderMethod(BMPPersistenceManager.java:632)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.BMPPersistenceManager.findEntity(BMPPersistenceManager.java:316)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.findEntity(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:234)
        at org.jboss.ejb.EntityContainer.findSingleObject(EntityContainer.java:1112)
        at org.jboss.ejb.EntityContainer.find(EntityContainer.java:741)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:386)
        at org.jboss.ejb.EntityContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invokeHome(EntityContainer.java:1139)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.EntitySynchronizationInterceptor.invokeHome(EntitySynchronizationInterceptor.java:203)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invokeHome(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:187)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractInterceptor.invokeHome(AbstractInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.EntityInstanceInterceptor.invokeHome(EntityInstanceInterceptor.java:137)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.EntityLockInterceptor.invokeHome(EntityLockInterceptor.java:76)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.EntityCreationInterceptor.invokeHome(EntityCreationInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor.invokeHome(CallValidationInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:125)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.runWithTransactions(TxInterceptorCMT.java:350)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.invokeHome(TxInterceptorCMT.java:161)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.process(SecurityInterceptor.java:230)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invokeHome(SecurityInterceptor.java:205)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.security.PreSecurityInterceptor.process(PreSecurityInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.security.PreSecurityInterceptor.invokeHome(PreSecurityInterceptor.java:88)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invokeHome(LogInterceptor.java:132)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invokeHome(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:107)
        at org.jboss.ejb.EntityContainer.internalInvokeHome(EntityContainer.java:527)
        at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:1046)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.invocation.local.LocalInvoker$MBeanServerAction.invoke(LocalInvoker.java:169)
        at org.jboss.invocation.local.LocalInvoker.invoke(LocalInvoker.java:118)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invokeLocal(InvokerInterceptor.java:209)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invoke(InvokerInterceptor.java:195)
        at org.jboss.proxy.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.jboss.proxy.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:68)
        at org.jboss.proxy.ejb.HomeInterceptor.invoke(HomeInterceptor.java:184)
        at org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(ClientContainer.java:101)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy261.findByPrimaryKey(Unknown Source)
        at com.mycompany.global.er.subsmngmnt.SubscriptionManagementImpl.findAccountByPrimaryKey(SubscriptionManagementImpl.java:60)
        at com.mycompany.global.er.transctrl.bl.AccountTransaction.validateUser(AccountTransaction.java:342)
        at com.mycompany.global.er.transctrl.purchase.ejb.PurchaseBean.purchasePackageMsisdn(PurchaseBean.java:1175)
        at com.mycompany.global.er.transctrl.purchase.ejb.PurchaseBean.purchasePackage(PurchaseBean.java:3611)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:386)
        at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:228)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:156)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.java:173)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor.invoke(CallValidationInterceptor.java:63)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:121)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.runWithTransactions(TxInterceptorCMT.java:404)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorCMT.invoke(TxInterceptorCMT.java:181)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.process(SecurityInterceptor.java:228)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:211)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:205)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:138)
        at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:650)
        at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:1029)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.invocation.local.LocalInvoker$MBeanServerAction.invoke(LocalInvoker.java:169)
        at org.jboss.invocation.local.LocalInvoker.invoke(LocalInvoker.java:118)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invokeLocal(InvokerInterceptor.java:209)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invoke(InvokerInterceptor.java:195)
        at org.jboss.proxy.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.jboss.proxy.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:68)
        at org.jboss.proxy.ejb.StatelessSessionInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInterceptor.java:112)
        at org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(ClientContainer.java:101)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy298.purchasePackage(Unknown Source)
        at com.mycompany.global.er.delegate.PurchaseApiDelegateImpl.purchasePackageMsisdn(PurchaseApiDelegateImpl.java:94)
        at com.mycompany.global.er.decoupling.process.PurchaseProcess.getResponse(PurchaseProcess.java:52)
        at com.mycompany.global.er.decoupling.process.PurchaseProcess.getResponse(PurchaseProcess.java:25)
        at com.mycompany.global.er.decoupling.AbstractProcess.process(AbstractProcess.java:126)
        at com.mycompany.global.er.decoupling.DecouplingProcessServlet.doPost(DecouplingProcessServlet.java:192)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at pk.mycompany.valves.PKAccessLogValve.invoke(PKAccessLogValve.java:547)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
        Caused by: org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -53ebf5fe:c4a3:55816e8f:b status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -53ebf5fe:c4a3:55816e8f:b status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:95)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
        ... 186 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -53ebf5fe:c4a3:55816e8f:b status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:370)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:496)
        at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:941)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89)
        ... 188 more
```

Here is the pertinent code:

```
@Stateless //only so we can inject an entityManager
public class AccountDaoImpl implements AccountDAO  {

    @EJB(beanInterface=MultiTenantEntityManager.class)
    private MultiTenantEntityManager multiem;
}
```

Because we have multi-tenancy, we can't just use a @PersistenceContext annotation - instead we need a multitenant entity manager as per [this example](http://www.hostettler.net/blog/2012/11/20/multi-tenancy/).

The DAO layer is called by the AccountBean:

```
//this is an EJB 2
public class AccountBean implements EntityBean, Account {

    AccountDAO mAccountDao;

    public void setEntityContext(EntityContext ctx)  {
      this.ctx = ctx;
      if (mAccountDao==null)
        mAccountDao = (AccountDAO) ctx.lookup("ercore/AccountDaoImpl/local");
    }


    public String ejbFindByPrimaryKey(String msisdn) throws FinderException  {

        mAccountDao.selectAccount(msisdn);
     }
}
```

Transactionality is configured on the AccountBean such that 'trans-attribute' is set to `Supports`.  I tried changing this to `Required` with no effect.

The subscription management layer is where the EJB2 account bean is loaded:

```
public class SubscriptionManagementImpl implements SubscriptionManagement  {

  public Account findAccountByPrimaryKey(String msisdn) throws EcommerceException {

     Account sAccount = getAccountHome().findByPrimaryKey(msisdn);
    }
}
```

This subscription management layer is in turn being called by the PurchaseBean:

```
public class PurchaseBean implements PurchaseTcApi, SessionBean     {

    public PurchaseAuthorization purchasePackage(String msisdn) throws RemoteException   {     

        Account account=getSubscriptionManagement(locale).findAccountByPrimaryKey(msisdn);

    }
```

And the PurchaseBean is being called by the delegate layer:

```
public class PurchaseApiDelegateImpl implements PurchaseApi {

    public PurchaseAuthorization purchasePackageMsisdn(String msisdn) throws PurchaseAuthorizationException         {

       getPurchaseBean().purchasePackage(clientApplicationId,
                msisdn, packageId, purchaseAttributes, this.locale);
}
```

And the delegate layer is in turn called by the servlet layer.  Phew!

So it's a pretty complicated setup, and I'm not going to pretend that I like it, but it was working fine until I started trying to move things to EJB3 (the AccountDaoImpl for now).

I suspect it might be something to with transaction boundaries.  I know that the default setting is `Required`, meaning join a transaction if there is one, otherwise create a new one.  So I can't see how the transaction can be inactive, since there should be one created as soon as we entered the method in AccountDaoImpl.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe probably looking too far ahead. The exception is

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection

Can you check if the credentials for the DB connection are correct and if the url of the DB is also good ?

Comment: the DB connection credentials are definitely fine, since they've not been changed, and other DB calls through the same app are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the actual root cause is not being exposed in these stack traces.
Could you connect your application through a debugger and check that the root cause exception is not swallowed somewhere. This root cause exception might have aborted your transaction and made it inactive.

Comment: I've debugged and found that the first exception caught is a `java.lang.UndeclaredThrowableException`, wrapping a `javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Cannot open connection`.  Doing a few `printStackTrace`s reveals a `javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active`  at the bottom. No obvious smoking gun.  But I too think that something else has made the transaction inactive - I'm just not sure what.

Comment: @mdarwin you means the application continued to run with a transaction inactive instead of stopping and rolling back immediately?